# Static (possibly constexpr) data member lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, static, c++14, data-members

The following code does not compile:

```
struct object 
{
    static constexpr auto f;
};

constexpr auto object::f = [](auto&& x){x += 1;};
```

neither this one:

```
struct object 
{
    static constexpr auto f = [](auto&& x){x += 1;};
};
```

but this does (when `f` is not a member):

```
static constexpr auto f = [](auto&& x){x += 1;};
```

Is there a way to declare and define a static constexpr data member lambda in C++14?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule on static data members is in [class.static.data]:

> If a non-volatile `const` `static` data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression* is a constant expression (5.19). A `static` data member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with the `constexpr` specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer*
>   in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression* is a constant expression.

Only `static const` integral/enumeration types or `constexpr` members can be defined within the class definition. C++14 disallowed `constexpr` lambdas period. The wording in [expr.const] used to read:

> A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>   — [...]
>   — a *lambda-expression* (5.1.2);
>   — [...]

So in C++14, you just can't have a static lambda data member - you can't define it inline and you can't define it out of line because you have no way of declaring it (variables declared with `auto` require an initializer). You're out of luck.

---

In C++17, we can have `constexpr` lambdas thanks to [p0170](http://wg21.link/p0170), at which point your second option is fine:

```
struct object 
{
    static constexpr auto f = [](auto&& x){x += 1;};
};
```